# Code to calculate SumProduct in a payroll system

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having issues to convert the below formula into a javascript:
=MAX(3000,MIN(MAX(0,INCOME-350000),50000)*5%+MIN(MAX(0,INCOME-400000),100000)*10%+MIN(MAX(0,INCOME-500000),100000)*15%+MAX(0,INCOME-600000)*20%-2000*CHILD).

I tried using
Math.max(3000, Math.min(Math.max(0,totalearnings-350000),50000)*5% + Math.min(Math.max(0,totalearnings-400000),100000)*10% + Math.min(Math.max(0,totalearnings-500000),100000)*15% + Math.max(0,totalearnings-600000)*20%-(2000*2)) but not working

Comment: That's an Excel formula that you wan't convert to Javascript. What does that have to do with PHP?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Add more details and clarity to the question such as explaining what does not work correctly.

Comment: PHP is the programming language that I have used for the payroll software. I am adding a javascript to execute the mentionned formula.

Comment: Is your problem understanding what this formula does or do you understand this formula and just can't implement it in JS? If it's the latter, maybe you could verbally describe what that formula does because many here (including me) are not that good with excel. I don't know the `SUMPRODUCT` function, but if you described what it does, I'd probably be able to implement that in JS ...

Comment: So if the taxable income is > than 350000,400000,500000,600000:
The calc will go as:
If the amt is 350001 to 400000 range, so =+MAX(SUMPRODUCT((D17>{amt between 350000 to 400000})*(D17-{amt between 350001 to 400000}),{0.05 which makes the 5%})
If the amt is 400001 to 500000 range, so =+MAX(SUMPRODUCT((D17>{amt between 400001 to 500000})*(D17-{amt between 400001 to 500000}),{0.05+0.05 which makes the 10%})
If the amt is 500001 to 600000 range, so =+MAX(SUMPRODUCT((D17>{amt between 500001 to 600000})*(D17-{amt between 500001 to 600000}),{0.05+0.05+0.05 which makes the 15%}) and so on

Comment: Please add additional explanation to the question (via the `Edit` link) and not in comments ...